# Node.js Expire Url (googlevideo redirect)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a node js web site and on some pages there are video players (with videos from my drive). My question is how to generate a url that gives access to the video only during a certain period. I see that many sites use videos from google drive and redirect using links similar to "https://r1---sn-q0cedn7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1584569784..."
how these sites generate that link. I was wondering if there any way to get this link through javascript, all the tutorials use PHP; -; I know it's possible to get the link through "googleapis" but i need a way to generate a url with expiration time. Thanks

Comment: Easiest thing to do is cryptographically sign a URL.  That way, you don't actually have to store anything but a key.  The data remains in the URL.

Comment: But I wanna make a expire link for src into a video tag, and with this method the original link will be displayed

Comment: Encrypt it.  Check out JWT with symmetric encryption.

Comment: If you're redirecting anyway... the URL is going to be visible, just keep that in mind.